# How to horizontally flip video from front camera using Android OpenCV?

Tags: android, opencv, camera

I am using OpenCV 2.4.9 on Android and modified the face detection example to take video from front Camera (i.e., `mOpenCvCameraView.setCameraIndex(1);`).
The video is mirrored/flipped horizontally. With some search in stackoverflow, I heard that it is hardcoded by the camera service, and maybe I need to flip it back myself.
How can I flip it back within the OpenCV example? I'm starting to use OpenCV and not familiar with its operations.

Comment: You could rotate Mat which is being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Core.flip()`. Be sure to import `org.opencv.core.core`